# How to clear previous delay effect when starting a new one in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have a worker saga that consist notifications logic. If response was ok - I push action to my store with data of successful info and then render appropriate message inside my "NotifyMessage" global component. All messages and type of message I receive from store. The same thing I do if response was not ok. After each error/success request I push action to my store with appropriate info. I use delay effect, wait for three seconds and after three seconds I push action to my store to hide my notify message.

The problem is when I try to make one request after another too quickly, there is still delay effect works from previous request. It seems like one message I can see for 2 seconds and another one for 1 second (still previous delay effect do his work). How can I cancel/clear previous delay effect in redux saga generator function (like clearTimeout in setTimeout) when I start a new one?

My sagas pattern is the following:

```
//Somewhere inside component:
<NotifyMessage alignText="center" type={notifyMsgType}>
     {notifyMsg}
</NotifyMessage>

//Store connection inside component
export default connect(
  ({ notify }) => ({
    notifyMsg: notify.message,
    notifyMsgType: notify.type,
 }),

import {
  CREATE_ITEM_FILTER,
  DELETE_ITEM_FILTER,
}
  from '../../components/manageFilters/actions';

import { createItemFilter } from './manageFilters/createItemFilter';
import { deleteItemFilter } from './manageFilters/deleteItemFilter';

export default function* root() { 
 yield takeEvery(CREATE_ITEM_FILTER, createItemFilter);
 yield takeEvery(DELETE_ITEM_FILTER, deleteItemFilter);
 and so on...
}


function* createItemFilter(action) {
try {
  if (response.ok) {
      const data = yield response.json();
      yield put(createItemFilterSuccess(data));
      //Update store with appropriate message and type
      yield put(showNotifyMessage([`Country ${country} was added to ${region} 
      region successfully`, 'success']));
      //Start timer
      yield delay(3000);
      //Hide notify message (clear 'message' and 'type' keys in store)
      yield put(hideNotifyMessage());
    }

} catch (e) {
    yield put(showNotifyMessage(['Error occurred during making request', 'error']));
    yield delay(3000);
    yield put(hideNotifyMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Since both patterns (my sandbox & your code) are almost identical, I think the delay you are experiencing might happen due to the response you are fetching. Can you check that?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work like I'm expected. In my example I use a different store structure (notify: {message: '', type: ''}) instead of array of notifications. The question  was how to cancel previous delay effect when new "showNotifyMessage" dispatched and I see one appropriate message for 3 seconds instead of collections like you do with react-tostify.

Comment: so every new message timer starts from 0 to 3 sec, if new "showNotifyMessage" action dispatched - we hide previous message and once again start timer from 0 to 3 sec (cancel previous timer)

Comment: Hi @Siarhei I was working on the sandbox to adapt the functionality as you have described here. Let me know if this is your expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved the problem by moving setTimeout to "NotifyMessage" component itself. When new message comes from store - I clear timeout and hide message after 3 seconds. It works as expected. I've totally removed delay effect from my workers sagas. I guess there is a better approach to solve this problem using only worker sagas (race effect and setTimeout?) but for now, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected in this sandbox (delay doesn't block other notifications) https://codesandbox.io/s/3q7402mp31

```
import * as types from './types';
import {
    cancelled,
    takeEvery,
    cancel,
    delay,
    fork,
    take
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

function* notification() {
    let notificationId = null;
    try {
        notificationId = toast(`Notification ⚡`);
        yield delay(3000);
        toast.dismiss(notificationId);
    } catch (e) {
        notificationId = yield toast.error(`Error`);
        yield delay(3000);
        toast.dismiss(notificationId);
    // The part of the saga that is triggered after cancel effect occurs
    } finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) toast.dismiss(notificationId);
    }
}
```

The notifications manager which responsible for cancellation of aborted notifications:

```
function* notificationManager() {
    const notify = yield fork(notification);
    yield take(types.SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
    yield cancel(notify); // Triggering cancel
}
```

The watcher saga

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(types.SHOW_NOTIFICATION, notificationManager);
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't work. Currently, I can't use react-tostify package in my project. Also, your example doesn't fit to my project sagas structure. As you might seen I put two array items to parameters (showNotifyMessage(['Error occurred during making request', 'error']). First one - message and the second one - type of error. I can't use things from react-tostify (notificationId) like in your example.

Comment: My intent isn't convince you to use react-toastify. I am using it because I don't have your code and the time for making notification components.. Good luck :)